# SelectPdf Html to PDF Image Not Appearing

Tags: selectpdf

I'm using SelectPDF to convert HTML to PDF

There's a section in the html for image:

```
<div>
    <img src="images\picture.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
```

There's no issue viewing the page in html
But when the html is converted the picture doesn't appear.

Answer (score 5):

This issue was in the toubleshooting section of Select PDF.

[https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/docs/html/Troubleshooting.htm](https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/docs/html/Troubleshooting.htm#item8)

I had to use a method that had both a template string and a base url string ConvertHtmlToString(string, string).